# angular UI bootstrap popup datepicker combined with ui.mask

Tags: datepicker, popup, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular UI bootstrap popup datepicker like the example here : 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

When i combine this with the uiMask Directive ( http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) the values in the input get scrambled when i pick a date.

I suspect because of the difference in type on the angular model : datepicker wants JS Date object/ ui.mask wants (masked) string.

When the picked date gets formatted/parsed by uiMask, it goes wrong :-/

Is what i am trying to do even possible ?

kind regards, Tom.

Comment: Can you show us some code?